# How do you determine values of $t$ such that the set $R$ is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is often important in applications to determine if a set of parametrized vectors is linearly independent.  The following set $R$ of three vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ provides an illustration of this common situation.

Let

$R = \{ (t,1,1), \; (1,t,1), \; (1,1,t) \}; \tag 1$

for which $t$ is the set $R$ linearly independent?

Comment: yes, I know how to compute a three order determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$\det R = \det \left ( \begin{bmatrix} t & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & t & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & t \end{bmatrix} \right ) = t^3 + 1 + 1 - t - t - t = t^3 - 3t + 2; \tag 1$

this determinant vanishes precisely when the rows/columns of the matrix are linearly dependent; in accord with (1), when

$t^3 - 3t + 2 = 0; \tag 2$

we have

$(t + 2)(t - 1)^2 = (t + 2)(t^2 - 2t + 1)$
$= t^3 - 2t^2 + t + 2t^2 - 4t + 2 = t^3 - 3t + 2 = 0; \tag 3$

the roots of $t^3 - 3t + 2$ are thus

$t = -2, 1; \tag 4$

for these values the rows/columns of the matrix are linearly dependent; for all other $t$, they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, using Latex:  I would not deal with determinants.  By the definition of "linearly independent" these three vector are independent if and only if there do NOT exist three numbers, a, b, and c, such that a(t,1,1)+ b(1,t,1)+ c(1,1,t)= 0.

And, of course, the best way to determine whether that is true or not is to try to find a, b, and c!

a(t,1,1)+ b(1,t,1)+ c(1,1,t)= (at+ b+ c, a+ bt+ c, a+ b+ ct)= (0, 0, 0) is equivalent to the three equations
at+ b+ c= 0
a+ bt+ c= 0
a+ b+ ct= 0

Solve for a, b, and c by eliminating c first.  Subtracting the second equation from the first, a(t-1)+ b(1-t)= 0.  Subtract the third equation from t times the second: $a(t-1)+ b(t^2-1)= 0$.  Both of those equations have a(t-1) so subtracting the first from the second eliminates a:  $b(t^2-t)= 0$.  As long as $t^2- t$ is not 0, we can divide by it to get b= 0.  Then we have a(t-1)= 0 and as long as t is not 1, a= 0 so that "at+ b+ c= 0" becomes c= 0.

"As long as $t^2- t$ is not 0" (Which includes t-1 is not 0) a, b, and c are all 0 so the three vectors are independent.

If $t^2- t= t(t- 1)= 0$ the vectors are dependent.  So the answer to the original question is "the three vectors are independent as long as t is not 0 or 1.

Comment: If you can express your math in $\LaTeX$, it would make your answer much more readable.  Cheers!